# Can I set a bluetooth pairing order with a Jambox?

Tags: bluetooth

I've paired multiple bluetooth devices with my [Jambox](http://jawbone.com/speakers/jambox/overview), but I can't figure out if there's a way to set an order for which device the Jambox will pair with when multiple paired devices are in range.

Both my Garmin and the UConnect system in my car support bluetooth precedence. For example, when I'm in my wife's car the UConnect will always pair with her phones first if they're around, but if not will pair with my phone instead. This is great as it means I don't have to change anything when I drive her car: it just works.

But it appears the Jambox favors the last device it was paired (call it `A`) with and will only pair with `B` if bluetooth is turned off on device `A` or it moves out of range. This means if my wife leaves the house and I use the Jambox while she's out I have to deactivate bluetooth on my phone before she can pair with it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the [MyTALK](http://mytalk.jawbone.com/jb2/mytalk/?2) software allows up to two bluetooth sources to pair with a Jambox simultaneously.

Once installed, Jambox settings can be modified from a computer via USB. Under the `Advanced Settings` menu previously paired bluetooth devices can be deleted but a pairing precedence cannot be set. The device will pair with the most recently paired devices.